# Selecting Change_Tracking_Current_Version() in SQL Server 2008 table trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2008 and Change tracking is enabled on my Database.
On one of my tables in the database, I have created the following Trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_student]
   ON [dbo].[Student]
   FOR UPDATE,DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
END
```

The purpose of this Trigger is - when I update or delete a record in table dbo.Student I should get the the Current change Tracking Version Id.

But when I update/delete a record in the table, CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() is not giving the current version_id but the previous version_id. After the trigger is fired,if I execute 
    select CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
I am getting the correct current version id.

So does the Change_Tracking_Current_Version() id change only after the trigger? Is there any method to get correct Change_Tracking_Current_Version() in the Trigger?

Comment: Hopefully this is just to demo the issue, but you should be aware that creating (returned) result sets in triggers is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933945.aspx), this function

> Returns a version that is associated with the last **committed** transaction.

*(Emphasis is mine.)*

While your trigger is executing, the transaction is not yet committed. So yes, the new value will be returned *after* the trigger.

Moreover, there's no way to obtain the new ID *in* a trigger, because, as specified [elsewhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994.aspx) in the manual,

> Change tracking is based on **committed** transactions.

*(Emphasis is mine.)*